# Store Stored Procedure Result With Multiple Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two Stored Procedures which receives multiple parameters.

`usp_stored_proc1` which returns a *uniqueidentifier* at the end of the stored procedure: `SELECT column1`

`usp_stored_proc2` which should get the `column1` as a parameter from the `usp_stored_proc1`

Here is my code:

```
EXEC usp_stored_proc1 'Test1', 'Para1', 'Para2'
EXEC usp_stored_proc2 SELECT column1, 'Para3', 'Para4'
```

and here is my attempt to pass the `usp_stored_proc1` as a parameter:

```
 EXEC usp_stored_proc2 usp_stored_proc1, 'Test1', 'Para1', 'Para2', 'Para3', 'Para4'
```

but failed.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) If you want to return a value, use either a user-defined function or an `OUTPUT` parameter.  `SELECT` doesn't *return* anything.

Comment: You cannot pass a "stored procedure" as a parameter to another stored procedure. And the only way to access a resultset produced by a stored procedure in tsql is to insert it into a table using the form <insert tbl (...) exec proc ...>. You will need many more steps to accomplish this without changing how your first procedure returns information to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GordonLinoff said in comments, you can use an `OUTPUT` parameter in your stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_stored_proc1
    @FirstParam NVARCHAR(50),
    --rest of parameters
    @Column1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --some stuff with input parameters
    
    SET @Column1 = NEWID()
END
```

And execute stored procedures like this:

```
DECLARE @Column1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

EXEC [dbo].usp_stored_proc1 'test', @Column1 OUTPUT

EXEC [dbo].usp_stored_proc2 @Column1,'param1'
```